# more effective way of finding mean in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large data frame with about 13 columns and 10,000 rows of data about apps. one of the columns is Category which states which category each app fall under, each app also has a value in the Ratings column which states the rating of the app. I'm trying to work out which category has the highest average rating.

I used this line of code to find out the different categories in the category column

```
df['Category'].value_counts())
```

so far I'm using this code to work out the mean, in this example I used it for the category 'Family'. it works but i have to do this for another 32 different categories, is there any simpler way to pick out specific categories from the overall data frame and work out the mean?

```
 family1 = app_data[['Category', 'App', 'Rating']]

 nan_family = family1[pd.notnull(family1['Rating'])]

 family2 = nan_family.loc[nan_family['Category'] == 'FAMILY']

 print(family2[['Rating']].mean(axis = 0))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need aggregate `mean` and then use [`Series.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) for `catagory` by maximal `mean`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'Rating':[np.nan,5,4,1,7,4,np.nan,6,np.nan],
         'Category':list('aaabbbccc')
})

print (df)
   Rating Category
0     NaN        a
1     5.0        a
2     4.0        a
3     1.0        b
4     7.0        b
5     4.0        b
6     NaN        c
7     6.0        c
8     NaN        c

print (df.groupby('Category')['Rating'].mean())
Category
a    4.5
b    4.0
c    6.0
Name: Rating, dtype: float64

top_cat = df.groupby('Category')['Rating'].mean().idxmax()
print (top_cat)
c
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a dataframe example like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['Game', 'Test1', 2.4], ['Game', 'Test2', 4.3],['News','Test3',5]], columns=['Category', 'App', 'Rating'])
```

Printing the dataframe:

```
  Category    App  Rating
0     Game  Test1     2.4
1     Game  Test2     4.3
2     News  Test3     5.0
```

You can then group by Categroy and calculate the mean value for all other colums for each category by:

```
df.groupby('Category').mean()
```

**Result:**

```
Category  Rating
Game        3.35
News        5.00
```

If you want to specifically calculate the mean of a single column (e.g. because you have more numeric columns), you will need to state the column explicitly like this:

```
df.groupby('Category')['Rating'].mean()
```